# How to redirect 404 error without changing the URL in PHP when all pages are loaded with index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I have developed a project where all files are loaded with index.php like `index.php?page=add-member` in this way, so now when I am doing `ind.php?page=add-member` so it is showing me the 404 not found error which is quite obvious or the normal behaviour but what do I want is that I want to include my custom `404.php` page but without changing the URL, so far I have used this but I am getting redirected to `404.php`.

.htaccess
`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

my index.php

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
include 'pages.php';
include $view;
```

pages.php

```
if (!empty($page)) {

 switch($page){
 case "add-member":
        $view =  'folders/add-member.php';
        break;
 }

}
```

So how can i do that.

Comment: There is no apparent reason why `ErrorDocument` specified like this, should change the current URL in the first place. You need to give us some more details here.

Comment: @CBroe what more details you required please specify it i will try to give my best.

Comment: Does your .htaccess contain anything else, specifically considering URL rewriting? And just to be clear, we are talking about “hard” 404s here, requests for _files_ that do not actually physically exist? Or are we talking about the case, where a `page` value gets passed to the actual index.php, for which your script logic then does not find any matching content to display (and you somehow trigger the 404 from within your script at this point)?

Comment: @CBroe Okay I am updating my question, please check, and I don't have any other code s in .htaccess.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated my question please check...

Comment: That code as currently shown makes no sense to begin with. You include `pages.php`, which tries to access `$page`, _before_ you even assigned a value to that variable.

Comment: Anyway, even if that was the other way around, it would not explain, why the web server should _redirect_ for actual, hard 404s. `/404.php` is a relative URL, a redirect should only happen, if you specified an absolute one. What does your `404.php` contain?

Comment: @CBroe This is what I have developed till now I just want to include my 404.php page template and show to the users when then may enter into wrong url.

Comment: @CBroe `404.php` has just a message `<p>Wrong returned page</p>`

Comment: “Including” would only make sense, if the request was handled by your index.php in the first place. Without any further URL rewriting, that would only apply to `index.php?page=XYZ` URLs, where your script logic has decided, that it did not find any content to show for `XYZ`. A URL such as `ind.php?page=…` would not trigger your index.php in the first place - a file named `ind.php` does not physically exist, so in _that_ case your specified ErrorDocument comes into play.

Comment: @CBroe yes I know that just for the 404 error I want to show the 404.php page but not redirecting to 404.php, because redirecting to 404.php changes the URL, I want the URL to be the same just it will show what 404.php has in it.

Comment: Again, as I said - not reproducible why this should cause any redirect in the first place.